# Bootstrap Typeahead using Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

for me it's the first time i'm using Bootstrap Typeahead.
I'd like to show, in typeahead, a list of 20 contacts formatted like this:

```
 Alex Steven +393333333333
.....
....
Lee Sloane +393323349530
```

As first step i write that:

```
typeahead: {
                source: function(queryForHints) {
                    if(queryForHints.length<4)
                        return '';

                    var parameters = {'queryForHints': queryForHints};
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "/thisroute",
                        data: parameters,
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {

                            return data;
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                        console.log("error for xxxxx/xxxxx");
                        },
                    async: true
                    });
                }
```

In the route i have an sql query that return an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => +393323243523
            [text] => Edan Constance (+393323243523)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => +393323349530
            [text] => Lee Sloane (+393323349530)
        )
```

in "data" result of ajax call i have (as a result success):

```
[Object, Object, .............. etc]
0
:
Object
text
:
"Dean Leandra (+393334029137)"
value
:
"+393334029137"
```

Now in consolle i get this error and nothing appear:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
```

How can i resolve my problem?

Comment: I don't see where you're appealing to the success property of an object... It seems you describe that when you inspect the data object in the success function you are getting what you expect.  I don't see where you attempt access to some objects success property... Can you show this?